# Why does inline-block "steal" 4px when float's doesn't

Tags: css, html

I have a simple page that should render an outer container of 1220px width with two inner sections, one that is 770px wide and one that is 330px wide. They have both 20px margin and the 770px have a padding set to 20px on left and right.

This makes

- 20+20+770+20+20+20+330+20 = 1220
- or ... margin + padding + section + padding + margin + margin + section + margin

When using float I can have the outer width set to 1220px and the inner widths set to 770 and 330 using the margin and padding to fill up the rest. This renders correct but I don't want the floats!

```
<div style="width: 1220px; background-color:#ffe4c4;">
    <section style="width: 770px; float: left; padding: 0 20px; margin: 20px; background-color: #ccc;">
        <!-- content goes here -->
        @RenderBody()
    </section>

    <section style="width: 330px; float: left; margin: 20px; background-color: #d8bfd8; padding: 0">
            <img src="/media/1155/menu_fake.jpg" width="330" />
    </section>
</div>
```

When using inline-block, I have to remove some pixels (4px to be exact) to make the elements display next to each other.

```
<div style="width: 1220px; background-color:#ffe4c4;">
    <section style="width: 766px; vertical-align:top; padding: 0 20px; margin: 20px; background-color: #ccc;">
        <!-- content goes here -->
        @RenderBody()
    </section>

    <section style="width: 330px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin: 20px; background-color: #d8bfd8; padding: 0">
            <img src="/media/1155/menu_fake.jpg" width="330" />
    </section>
</div>
```

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Read this http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inline-block` elements also render the white-space between the elements in the source. To eliminate them, you need to remove the white-spaces in your code.

More details [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)